# whacky closures and ajax questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm super confused by my code. Let me show what it looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

var customer_exists = false;
$.get(window.additional_parameters.customer_exists_url, "json")
    .done(function () {
        customer_exists = true;
    })
    .always(function () {
        // Don't make request to buy clickable until we know if the customer exists
        $('#request-to-buy').on('click', function(e) {
            request_to_buy(customer_exists);
        });
});

function request_to_buy(customer_exists) {

response = can_request_to_buy();

response.done(function (response) {
    if (customer_exists) {
        // Actually create the request on the server
        $.post(window.additional_parameters.request_to_buy_url,
              {'ticket_id': window.additional_parameters.ticket_id},
              "json")
            .done(function (response) {
                request_to_buy_success(response);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                var message = handle_ajax_response(response);
                show_ajax_message(message);
            });
    } else {
        show_pre_stripe_popup();
    }
})
.fail(function (response) {
    var error_message = handle_ajax_response(response);
    show_ajax_message(error_message, 'danger');
});
}
```

`$(document).ready()`, we set a variable called customer_exists. This variable guides the path of the code afterwards and is pretty important. If the `$.get` AJAX request is successful, it's true, otherwise it remains it default value of false. After the AJAX response, we attach a click event to "#request-to-buy." My goal here is to create a closure and pass in the value of customer_exists that was just set. This doesn't happen.

A good portion of the time ( I had it work correctly once or twice ), when I inspect request_to_buy in the debugger, I can see that customer_exists is a jQuery click event. why ??? Shouldn't it take on the value of the customer_exists from the surrounding scope of where the function was created? Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thank you

EDIT: Here's a little more information that describes how it works sometimes...
The first time that I click '#request-to-buy', the handler is

```
function(e) {
            request_to_buy(customer_exists);
        }
```

This is what we would expect. e contains the click event, customer_exists retains it's value, and everything works inside request_to_buy.

Every time I click '#request-to-buy' after the first, instead of the above function being called, request_to_buy is called directly, and instead of passing in customer_exists in the first parameter, the click event is passed in instead. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is there some point in running `request_to_buy()` when `customer_exists == false`? If not, then it would appear that you can simply rearrange the initial `$get()` to call `request_to_buy()` only on success, and to call `show_pre_stripe_popup()` in an error handler.

Comment: Something untoward must be happening elsewhere, probably in `can_request_to_buy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this without the need for the cumbersome outer var `customer_exists`.

For example :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.get(window.additional_parameters.customer_exists_url, "json").then(function () {
        // Don't make request to buy clickable until we know if the customer exists
        $('#request-to-buy').on('click', request_to_buy);
    }, function() {
        $('#request-to-buy').on('click', show_pre_stripe_popup);
    });

    function request_to_buy(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        can_request_to_buy().then(function(response) {
            // Actually create the request on the server
            $.post(window.additional_parameters.request_to_buy_url, {
                'ticket_id': window.additional_parameters.ticket_id
            }, "json").then(request_to_buy_success, function() {
                show_ajax_message(handle_ajax_response(response));
            });
        }).fail(function(response) {
            show_ajax_message(handle_ajax_response(response), 'danger');
        });
    }
}
```

`show_pre_stripe_popup` will also be passed an event and you may need to do `e.preventDefault();` there too.

You will need to check that the correct parameters are passed to the various error handlers. I can't verify them.

If it still doesn't work, then you must suspect other code that's not included in the question, for example the function `can_request_to_buy()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var customer_exists = false;
```

Declare this outside of ready block.

Comment: Because the variable is defined inside ready block and hence the scope is limited.  At the time ajax finishes and actually calls the function with the parameter... It is lost or has old value.